# Different current time produces through XSLT and Java

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have two services running on separate machine. I'm seeing strange behavior in the boxes when generating the current time. The current time is being generated differently.

In one machine it's being done in XSLT using `current-dateTime()` function e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="dateNow" select="format-dateTime(adjust-dateTime-to-timezone(current-dateTime()), '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01]')"/>
```

In the second machine, the current time is being generated in Java code using Joda Time e.g.`DateTime.now()`

Why is box one 1h ahead of box two?

I've checked the current time in and the time zone in both machine. They are the same.

**Update:**

Originally I thought it was time zone issue which is why I added `adjust-dateTime-to-timezone` . `adjust-dateTime-to-timezone` has no effect.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with it. Originally I thought it was time zone issue which is why I added it.`adjust-dateTime-to-timezone` has no effect.

Comment: In that case, okay. And what are you doing with the Joda-time one? What are you seeing that lets you see a difference, and what do you do that lets you see this? (Would be smart to answer that kind of questions before it's asked)

Comment: @kumesana I just wanted to keep it simple. All the app does is gets the current time and updates a field with current time. Obviously, the app does other things but nothing related to time. Essentially the apps populate fileds and passes it onto the next service to process.

Comment: Sure, I like simple. Simple things 1: what do you see? Simple thing 2: what is the code that produces that thing you see?

Comment: Some basic troubleshooting: compare the two methods on the same machine; compare the two machines using the same method.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "different boxes" I assume you mean different computers. The most likely explanation is that the default timezone is set differently on the two machines.

Comment: Yep I mean different computers